# Good .NET ORM Framework that supports OleDb and Stored Procedures?

Tags: .net, orm, oledb

A typical stored procedure in our system accepts around 20 or so parameters.  There's no chance of refactoring these stored procedures either.  I've basically resorted to writing my own code generator that wraps these SP's into (database provider agnostic) "Command" objects, with their public properties corresponding to the SP parameters.  It works, but I'd prefer a 3rd party tried and tested solution.

Can anyone recommend anything?  I haven't found one that supports OleDB and stored procedures.

Edit:  I need OleDb connectivity because of SQL 6.5 (believe it or not).  ADO.NET cannot connect to SQL 6.5.  Also, this is a .NET 2.0 application, so LinqToSql is of no use to me.

Edit2:  I've already tried nHibernate and iBatis.  Neither of them suit my needs.  The last time I tried nHibernate it required that the SP return a result set.  That isn't the case with my SPs.  Both of them also require me to manually specify the parameters.

Comment: Which framework did you pick? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experience with 3 ORM layers:

- [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)
- [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/)
- [.NET Tiers](http://nettiers.com)

All three are free, support OleDb connections, and stored procedures.

Subsonic - This one was built specifically for web applications. It mimics a lot of what Ruby On Rails does. They just added migrations. Subsonic is the lightest of the three. It's a tad harder to use for Winforms, but not as hard as I though it would be. It comes with a nice UI tool to generate the code and maintain database settings. This is the only one that has support for different databases. I've used it with SQLite, SQL Server CE, and SQL Server.

CSLA.NET - This one can pretty much handle pretty much all of the new and shinny .NET technologies. I know that the author just added support for WCF, WPF, and Silverlight. This is what I use when I need very heavy lifting with enterprisey type apps. It has a lot of nice features like unlimited object undo, the ability to mark collections as read only, and the ability to move and anchor objects anywhere you want. This is the closest you will get to what JBoss does on Java.

Net Tiers - I'm not a big fan, but it will get the job done. It's lighter than CSLA, but still heavier than Subsonic.

I would to also mention [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html), [Castle Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html), and [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib). I don't have much experience with these though.

Comment: Are you sure Subsonic supports OleDB?

Comment: Is your answer still valid today? It's been 4.5 years. I just landed on this question today, which means the question still is. I think Entity Framework has become more relevant, so I wonder what you would recommend nowadays.

Comment: I have successfully used ServiceStack.OrmLite with both SQL Server and SQLite OleDb providers. I heard that Dapper also works as well with OleDb providers. I believe EF 5.0 now supports OleDb.

See these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125434/sqlce-4-0-ef-5-0-stopped-working-in-vs2012
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322023/dapper-ms-access-read-works-write-doesnt

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard ADO .NET Entitry framework has litle support on stored procedures... LINQ2SQL you can make it work but may require somekind of a proxy class... NHibernate and IBatis is your best bet...

Answer (score -1):

Alternatives:

1. LINQ to SQL
2. ADO.NET Entity Framework
3. NHibernate
4. Your choice )