# Dapper & MS Access - Read works, Write doesn't

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, oledb, dapper

Let's start by getting this out of the way: I'm stuck using an MS Access DB and I can't change it.

This works fine:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
  conn.Open();
  var results = conn.Query<string>(
    "select FirstName from Students where LastName = @lastName", 
    new { lastName= "Smith" }
  );
  conn.Close();
}
```

This works fine:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
    "update Students set FirstName = @firstName, City = @city where LastName = @lastName", 
    conn
  );
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstName", "John");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("city", "SomeCity");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastName", "Smith");

  conn.Open();
  var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();
}
```

This doesn't... it executes without error but it sets the FirstName as "SomeCity" in the DB and the City as "John":

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
  conn.Open();
  var results = conn.Query<string>(
    "update Students set FirstName = @firstName, City = @city where LastName = @lastName", 
    new { firstName = "John", city = "SomeCity", lastName = "Smith" }
  );
  conn.Close();
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT BELOW**

Dapper works if I use DynamicParameters:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
  DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
  parameters.Add("firstName", "John");
  parameters.Add("city", "SomeCity");
  parameters.Add("lastName", "Smith");

  conn.Open();
  var result = conn.Query<string>(
    "update Students set FirstName = @firstName, City = @city where LastName = @lastName",
    parameters
  );
  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: That's odd.. I'll need to try to repro...

Comment: Note: Just tried to reproduce with sql express 2008 and it works fine...

Comment: I've done this successfully with Sql Server... so I think this is with MS Access only

Comment: @MarcGravell See the accepted answer below, and my comment... do you know if removing the `.OrderBy(p => p.Name)` code will affect other parts of Dapper?

Comment: @Trev intriguing; I will have to check

Comment: According to a comment to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19481354/2144390), this is no longer an issue with the current version of Dapper.

Comment: @GordThompson the issue is not fixed still. We need to preserve the order still. Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339478/dapper-with-access-update-statement-partially-not-working

Comment: @RobinAtTech - Thanks for the update. I seem to recall testing a subsequent version of *Dapper* itself and confirming that it no longer sorted the parameters by name, but it was quite a while ago and I can no longer be certain of that. I wonder if Dapper-*Extensions* may still be sorting the parameters by name, perhaps because it is still tied to an older version of Dapper. (Dapper-Extensions on GitHub has not been updated in over two years.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some digging, I was able to find a cause:

Below is CreateParamInfoGenerator delegate from dapper's SqlMapper:

```
    public static Action<IDbCommand, object> CreateParamInfoGenerator(Identity identity)
    {

        // code above here
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = type.GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
```

The props is your unanimous param which gets re-ordered by OrderBy(p => p.Name), which moves city upfront.

```
new { firstName = "John", city = "SomeCity", lastName = "Smith" }
```

Props is then being added to the IDbCommand Parameters where the order is important.

If I comment out OrderBy() clause, then everything works.

I also tested DynamicParameters and intentionally re-ordered the attributes to move city upfront:

```
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("city", "SomeCity");
        parameters.Add("firstName", "John");
        parameters.Add("lastName", "Smith");

        var result = dbConnection.Query<string>(
          "update Students set FirstName = @firstName, City = @city where LastName = @lastName",
          parameters
        );
```

The above did not work as well, so the order of attributes is the reason!

I guess you can modify your local copy of SqlMapper for now and remove OrderBy() and wait for an official verdict from Marc...

Hope this helps.

Comment: It turns out MS Access is [fussy about the order of the parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1476818/47121).  I tried removing the `.OrderBy(p => p.Name)` code from SqlMapper and it works now.  I'd also like to know from Marc or Sam whether removing this code would have any implications elsewhere.

Comment: I did not know that as well; good to know! And I'm also curious about the purpose of the OrderBy() clause.

Comment: According to a comment to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19481354/2144390), this is no longer an issue with the current version of Dapper.

Comment: Having this issue still on 1.42 from NuGet.

Comment: @Bob Having this issue still in 1.50.2

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, what I did was to `use parameter names like @param1, @param2` instead of @name,@id,@price so the order stays the same without having to modify SQLMapper.cs file.

Something like

```
public void Update(Movie movie)
{
  var sql = "UPDATE myDB.movies set title=@param1, genre=@param2 where ID=@param3";
  db.Execute(sql, new { param1 = movie.Title, param2 = movie.Genre, param3 = movie.ID });
}
```

Comment: Things may have changed since you last worked with Dapper. According to a comment to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19481354/2144390), this is no longer an issue with the current version.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the link. I am having the same problem with version 1.13 via NuGet.

Comment: I am having same issue in 1.50.2