# Dapper with MS Access Update and Insert issue

Tags: c#, ms-access, dapper

I am using Dapper to Update and Insert Access DB. Code is working not throwing exception but its not updating the value in DB. Below is my code

```
sql.Append("UPDATE drugs_repository SET drug_name = @DrugName ");

sql.Append(" WHERE id = @DrugId");

var parameters = new
{
    DrugName = objDrug.DrugName,                           
    DrugId = objDrug.DrugId
};
var t = connection.Query<string>(sql.ToString(), parameters);
```

Can someone please let me know what exactly I am missing in the above code?
When I hardcode the value than its updating in the DB. So probably its related to parameter.

Comment: Got the issue. In SqlMapper.cs file of Dapper I removed orderby from "//IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0).OrderBy(p => p.Name);". its working fine now. Not sure whether removing orderby will have any implications. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 Well done! Because `'@DrugName' > '@DrugId'` the `.OrderBy` was swapping the order of the parameters, and Access.OLEDB requires that the parameters be created in the order in which they appear in the SQL CommandText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are nervous about possible side-effects from removing the `.OrderBy()` in the Dapper code then a workaround would be to name your parameters in such a way that they will sort in the same order that they appear in the SQL command. For example, I suspect that the unmodified Dapper code would probably work okay if the parameters were named `@1DrugName` and `@2DrugId`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was actually using the older version of Dapper. In latest version it's fixed. Anyways thanks for the reply. techknackblogs.com

Comment: I think the issue still exist unless the order is kept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339478/dapper-with-access-update-statement-partially-not-working